# Field can be converted to local variable error while using spinner

Tags: android, spinner

1. ### **This problem happens on the line private Spinner spItems;,i am new to android ,so i can't understand whats happening .**

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements      OnItemSelectedListener{
   private Spinner spItems;
   ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
   List<String> listData=new ArrayList<String>();

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       listData.add("Nexus");
       listData.add("iPhone");
       listData.add("Nokia");
       listData.add("Samsung");
       listData.add("HTC");
       listData.add("Motorola");

       spItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spItems);

       arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.row_spinner, listData);
       arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.row_spinners_dropdown);
       spItems.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

       spItems.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id){
       Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
       if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spItems){
           String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
           Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}}

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
   {}}
   ```

Comment: Really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: if any error occur then paste your logcat.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're using Android Studio? It's not a full blown error: your code will still compile and run just fine, but Android Studio is letting you know that you've declared `spItems` as an instance variable of the `MainActivity` class, but you don't actually need it to be one. It can be safely converted to an inline, local variable instead.